# conflict between the same class or id of multiple css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to stop the conflict between same class or id of multiple css files. As I am explaining below for better understanding:

There is a master web page which has several `<div>` but there is a `<div class"dynamic">` which always reload the contents including `css files`. Let's suppose if any class of master page has the same name to reloaded elements' class while properties are different. Then how should I handle this to stop the conflict.

***master.html***

```
<html> 
    <head> //attached master.css file here </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="myClass"> </div>
        <div class="dynamic"> /* often reload elements by ajax */ </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

***master.css***

```
.myClass { height: 100px; width: 150px; background : red;}
.dynamic { height: 200p; width: 200px; }
```

*now i am showing the reloaded html elements & css files into `dynamic div` of master page*

```
reloaded tag line by ajax : <div class"myClass"> </div>
```

***reload.css***

```
.myClass{height: 30px; width: 25px; background: yellow; }
```

Now as you can see there are two classes with same name but different properties. Then how should I stop the confliction?

***@Edit*** Thanks everyone for your support & time but my problem is different here.
 the dynamic reloaded contents & css files are streaming from the client/user machine while `master html page & it's css` streaing directly from server.
 so whatever the contents loads in dynamic div, it's coming from client side (`e.g. tag lines & css, js`). in that case i am not able to handle the css file which is just reloaded by `ajax()` so i think it can be sort out using `js/jQuery fn()`.

Comment: as i know, if i write like this in `reload.css :  .dynamic> .myClass {...}` then problem will be sort  out but i want to know other method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the cascading rules of the CSS:

In your case, `div.myClass` inside `div.dynamic` should override `div.myClass` belongs to the `body`.

you adjust the `reload.css` rules to

```
.dynamic .myClass{height: 30px; width: 25px; background: yellow; }
```

The cascading rules which are applied when **determine which rules should apply to html div** could be referenced [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

### Updated 11.23

As the OP only have control over `master.css`, the above solution won't work. Thus, I suggest use **child selector** to limit the CSS rules to only the outer `div.myClass`. Modify the rule in your `master.css` to:

```
body > .myClass {...}
```

This rule will **only apply** to the `.myClass` which is the child of `body`. It leaves the spaces of styling for inner `.myClass` div.

Comment: exactly this is excellent to sort out but this rule is impossible to apply here  because of the reloaded dyanmic contents (`elements & css file`) comes from the client while `master html page contents ` at server side.

Comment: @user1010399 you mean you only have control over the `master.css` but you don't have control over `reload.css`?

Comment: yes, I only have control over `master.css` while `reload.css or anyName.css` file is of the client/user so i have no control over that.

Comment: @user1010399 I updated the post to include on solution in your case.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** A more specific selector

```
.dynamic .myClass { }
```

This selector selects the `.myClass` element that is a descendent of `.dynamic`.

```
.dynamic > .myClass { }
```

This selector selects the `.myClass` element that is a direct child of `.dynamic`.

---

**Option 2:** Inline CSS

```
<div class="dynamic">
    <div class="myClass" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Option 3:** Use a different class.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to avoid the previous defined property to be overwritten by a later defined value, you can use the `!important` syntax.

```
.myClass { background-color: red !important; } /* Sets the property to red */
.myClass { background-color: yellow; } /* Property is NOT overwritten */
```

If I understand your question correctly, this should sort it.

So you should add `!important` to the properties that seem to be overwritten.

Comment: thanks Tim !but my problem is bit different here, let me clarify bit more the question

Comment: yes but i felt steven's answer is very correct and he explained too.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.myclass { ble ble }

div.main div.myclass { ble ble }

<body>
 <div class="myclass"></div>
 <div class="main><div class="myclass"></div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whichever css class of the same name is loaded last will overwrite anything set by the earlier class. However, if you use an inline style attribute this will always take precedence over anything set by the css file (so using an inline style is one option).

You could also use different style names or clarify your style with tag names `div.myClass` or id's `#myDiv.myClass`.

Comment: Thanks Barry ! is there any way to strict the reloaded new css with the tag line only